# Sumo-bot Wheel Help - Sticky tires or Wide & less friction tires?

Tags: friction

I am building a sumo-bot and our competitors have thin sticky tires, while we have wider and less sticky tires. The diameter is the same, and the gearbox/motor is the same. Who will win?

PS: Sticky tires: https://www.pololu.com/product/694 & wide tires: https://www.pololu.com/product/62

Comment: What leads you to think that the tire friction is the sole factor that will determine who wins the competition.  Offhand, I'd say that sounds like a relatively naive assumption.

Comment: Voting to close - this question is far too broad and does not have anywhere near enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you asked the same question, at the same time, on (at least) 2 *other* sites, [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209779/for-a-sumo-bot-should-i-have-sticky-thin-tires-or-wide-and-less-sticky-tires) and [robotics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/high-traction-thin-tires-vs-wide-moderate-traction-tires-sumo-bot)

Comment: I'm voting to open because the question is clear to me (and obviously to Chuck also, who has been able to answer it), and also because I think it fits better here than on the other sites.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming *everything* about the vehicles is the same - **mass especially**, but also shape, center of gravity, etc., such that the entire problem boils down to tire grip, you will lose.

See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/154485) for more information, but essentially, *assuming your vehicle weight is low enough that you're not going to deform the competition surface*, static friction is given by:

$$
F_{\mbox{friction}} = \mu_{\mbox{static}} P_{\mbox{tire}} A
$$

where $\mu_{\mbox{static}}$ is the static coefficient of friction, $P_{\mbox{tire}}$ is the pressure the tires exert on the ground, and $A$ is the contact surface area. However, because:

$$
P_{\mbox{tire}} = \frac{F_{\mbox{normal}}}{A}
$$

where $F_{\mbox{normal}}$ is the [normal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force) of the vehicle, you wind up with:

$$
F_{\mbox{friction}} = \mu_{\mbox{static}} \frac{F_{\mbox{normal}}}{A} A
$$

or

$$
F_{\mbox{friction}} = \mu_{\mbox{static}} F_{\mbox{normal}}
$$

So, again, assuming *everything* else about the two robots is the same, and that you're not operating on a surface like mud or something else that will appreciatively deform under the tires, then the traction/friction force will be higher in the vehicle with a higher coefficient of friction.

That is, your tires should start slipping before theirs do, and since [static friction is greater than dynamic friction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/569), once your tires start to slip they get a significant "pushing" advantage over you.